# How to use Finite Automaton to implement a scanner

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, finite-automata

I'm building a simple scanner. Suppose I have the following tokens defined for my language:

```
!, !=, !==, <, <<, {
```

Now I can specify them using regular expressions, so:

```
!=?=? | { | <<?
```

Then I used http://hackingoff.com to build NFA and DFA. Each machine now can determine if the input is in the language of regexp or not. But my program is a sequence of tokens, not one token:

```
!!=!<!==<<!{
```

My question is **how I should use the machines to parse the string into tokens**? I'm interested in the approach rather then implementation.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @melpomene, my question is what to do then with these machines? how to parse the actual string of many tokens?

Comment: Are you asking us to write code for you?

Comment: @melpomene, the approach, I don't mention code anywhere

Comment: If you're not talking about code, then I don't know what you mean by "approach".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common rule is "maximal munch", which always selects the longest possible token.

In general, the algorithm to scan a single token using a DFA is as follows: (To tokenise an input, this algorithm is repeated until the end of the input is reached, with each scan starting at the input cursor left by the previous scan.)

Set the DFA state to the start state. Then, for each input character in sequence:

- if the DFA has a transition on the character, move to the iindicated state. If that state is an accepting state, record the current input cursor and the state number.
- otherwise, rewind the input to the last recorded accept position and return the recorded state number.

Here, the accepting state number is used to indicate which token was encountered. In practice, it is common to associate each accepting state with a token code, because some token types will have more than one accepting state.

It is not always necessary to use the backtracking algorithm described above. In some cases, analysis of the DFA will reveal that the last accepting state was always at the immediately preceding input position. However, many languages require backtracking.

For example, a language in which `.` and `...` are both tokens but not `..` (such as C) must backtrack on input `..1`, which should be tokenised as `.`, `.1`. In the tokenisation of this input, the first scan will accept the first `.`, continue with the second `.` (which is not an accepting state) and then fail to find a transition on the input `1`. It will then report that it found a `.` (the recorded accepted token) and reset the input cursor to the second character position, so that the next scan will see the token `.1`.

Comment: I actually saw a paper once about an algorithm that can do regex-based maximum-munch tokenization in O(n) (i.e. without backtracking). It's just not used in practice.

Comment: @sepp2k: if you have a reference, I'd love to see it. I don't believe O(N) lexing is possible in general in constant space, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. (If you relax the space constraint, then it should be doable, but that is a lot less interesting.) In practical languages, with the addition of patterns for things like unterminated strings and comments, it is usually possible to limit backtracking to O(1) characters, in which case tokenisation is O(N). So the motivation to use a more complicated algorithm is limited.

Comment: @rici, thanks a lot. I've found the following: _The dfa should run until it reaches the point where the current state, S, has no
outgoing transition on the next character. At that point, the implementation
must decide which regural expression it has matched. If
S is an accepting state, then the dfa has found a word in the language and
should report the word and its syntactic category._

Comment: _Otherwise, if the dfa passed through one or more accepting states on its way to S, the recognizer
should back up to the most recent such state. This strategy matches
the longest valid prefix in the input string. If it never reached an accepting
state, then no prefix of the input string is a valid word and the recognizer
should report an error._

Comment: it seems to be exactly what you're suggesting in your answer, correct?

Comment: @angularindepth: yes, precisely.

Comment: I've found the paper I was thinking of: [“Maximal-Munch” Tokenization in Linear
Time](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=276394).

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks. That URL is paywalled but I found an earlier version on the author's host university. As I suspected, it is not a constant-space algorithm; it is true that it avoids quadratic worst-case behaviour, but very few practical programming language tokenisers suffer from this problem.

Comment: @rici, cool, thanks. _However, many languages require backtracking_ - so would that be an implementation of NFA? Or it will still be converted into DFA without backtracking?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: Not at all. The backtracking is precisely what I refer to in the last step of the algorithm: when you reach a state with no transition, you backtrack to the last input position corresponding to an accepting state. (The text you quote explicitly uses the words "back up to " :) ) Also: The usual NFA algorithm doesn't backtrack. It explores all possible traces in parallel.

Comment: @rici, I got it, thanks. It's **not** backtracking to try another path which potentially can lead to an end state, it backtracking to find if the accepted state was encountered during the current path, correct?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: It knows that the accepted state was encountered, so it knows that the accepted state is at the end of the token. It backtracks so that the *next scan* starts at the right place.

Comment: @rici, aha, and so what state does it backtrack to? start state? I'd apprecite if you added to your answer a basic example that shows such backtracking

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: The scan algorithm starts with "Set the DFA state to the start state." It is not backtracking the state. It is backtracking the *input cursor* so that the *next scan* starts at the *correct place* in the input.

Comment: @rici, thanks, I think understand I now. Every time the scanner starts parsing for the next token it runs the machine from the start, correct?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: Right. (In certain programming languages, the action for an accepted token can change the starting state. Ecmascript tokenisation of regular expressions is a slightly horrible example.)